# 'XImage' does not contain a definition for 'GetFrameCount'

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am attempting to create a multi-page TIFF to PDF converter. I have followed what appears to be good code from multiple sources on the Internet. I have PDFsharp-gdi installed, and I have included the proper libraries, I believe.

The problem is that I am getting the error message:

> Error  CS1061  'XImage' does not contain a definition for 'GetFrameCount' and no extension method 'GetFrameCount' accepting a first argument of type 'XImage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
using System.IO;
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
...
for (int i = 0; i < prePdfFiles.Count; i++)
{
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
    XGraphics xgr;
    XImage img = XImage.FromFile(destPath + prePdfFiles[i]);
    int pagesCount = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
    for( int j = 0; j < pagesCount; j++ )
    {
        img.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, j);
        PdfPage currentPage = new PdfPage();
        doc.Pages.Add(currentPage);
        xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(currentPage);
        XImage ximg = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);
        xgr.DrawImage(ximg, 0, 0);
    }
    doc.Save(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(destPath + prePdfFiles[i], ".pdf"));
    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't know your sources, but your `img` object should be of class `Image` while the `ximg` object should remain class `XImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `XImage` does not have that method, use the `Image` class and convert to `XImage` later on.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. It did fix the problem.